# Loading Bitmaps and Storing them Statically Alternatives?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, garbage-collection

I have created a small applicaiton (a **game**), that reuses the same set of images several times. SO i thought i should create a class that is responsible for loading all of the different images once, from which i can then access them statically from other classes. However, i believe this may have caused an issue with the Garbage Collector, which causes my App to lag whenever the GC is run. Here is What the ImgLoader class looks like:

```
public class ImgLoader extends View {
public static Bitmap tree1;

public ImgLoader(Context context) {
    super(context);
    loadImgs();
}

public void loadImgs() {
    System.gc(); // Manually Call GC

    // TREES
    tree1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tree);
    tree1 = getResizedBitmap(tree1, MainActivity.height / 2,
            MainActivity.width / 10);
}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height,
            matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}

public static Bitmap RotateBitmap(Bitmap source, float angle) {
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle);
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
            source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}

}
```

Note, i only use one Bitmap for the question. Essentially, when i want to use an image in my application, i say:

```
object.image = ImgLoader.tree1;
```

What is an alternative to doing this, that is not so memory intensive?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like **very bad practice** to me, especially because you are loading **multiple `Bitmaps`** and keep **static** references of them.

Since even small `Bitmaps` consume considerably large amounts of memory, you will run into `OutOfMemoryErrors` very soon.

A `Bitmap` 512x512 already consumes **1 Megabyte** of RAM (in 32 Bit) color. You can load your Bitmaps in `RGB_565` (16 Bit) to reduce memory consuption.

Why not just load the `Bitmap` from the `Resources` when you need it?

Comment: I would do that, but i need to resize them every time to fit them to the screen.

Comment: I still dont see why resizing a Bitmap would require a static reference to it?

Comment: Im just saying, so each time i load it, i would have to call the re-size method with it. Would that not be inefficient?

Comment: Are you developing a game and require like 50FPS? If not, just test it on a device and im 99% sure its gonna be just fine concerning performance. Resizing it everytime is definitely better than a static reference to a Bitmap.

Comment: Yes, im developing a game. So there cant be any lag.

Comment: Allright, that would be a good thing to be mentioned in your question. I will edit that.

Comment: Im Sorry. Didnt think it mattered very much, but your right.

Comment: So you suggest that i load them whenever i need them and convert them to 16 bit for most efficient results?

Comment: For most efficiency concerning memory consumption yes. Unfortunately I am not well enough experienced in game development that I can make anymore suggestions. I am not sure how big the performance loss will be when you load the Bitmap on every frame.

Answer (score 0):

try getting them in InputStream format ... they will be in byte .. but personnaly,( and its really personnally )  i prefer to load every image when i need it instead of leaving them in a memory .. for future use , the number of images can increase , plus , as u mentionned and i noticed in your code , the images are store locally (  not doenloaded ) so  it shldnt b a big problem to reload them .. but again its my own opinion

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it has anything to do with the gc; you are loading images when you manually call the gc.

I believe it's the loading of images that is causing your app to lag.  You could load the bitmap asynchronously.

Comment: I only load them at the start. And the apps runs fine and then lags every time the GC runs.

Comment: What are you using to monitor garbage collection?  From your code above, it's only being manually triggered when you load images.